# Configure my model so that a field can reference many different types of classes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Let's say that I have a `Company` model and a `Product` model, both of which have an `UserUploadedImage` associated with them.  I want to create my `UserUploadedImage` in a way such that I can write `image.parent` and that will reference either the `Product` or the `Company`, whichever is appropriate in that case.

I realize I can store a second column in `UserUploadedImage` with either `Product` or `Company` and have a conditional to look up the appropriate value.  I am, however, not sure where the optimal place to put this code is, or whether there is a cleaner way of achieving my goal.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need to look at is Polymorphic Associations

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations

**Polymorphic Associations**

A slightly more advanced twist on associations is the polymorphic association. With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association. For example, you might have a picture model that belongs to either an employee model or a product model.

```
class Picture < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :imageable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :pictures, :as => :imageable
end
```

You can think of a polymorphic belongs_to declaration as setting up an interface that any other model can use. From an instance of the Employee model, you can retrieve a collection of pictures: *@employee.pictures*.

Similarly, you can retrieve *@product.pictures*.

If you have an instance of the Picture model, you can get to its ***parent*** via *@picture.imageable*. To make this work, you need to declare both a foreign key column and a type column in the model that declares the polymorphic interface:

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string  :name
      t.integer :imageable_id
      t.string  :imageable_type
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

This migration can be simplified by using the t.references form:

```
class CreatePictures < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pictures do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.references :imageable, :polymorphic => true
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```